# ImageField variable in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates

So I have looped over an object variable in the respective template in Django, every item loops over well except the image variable. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. But here are my codes:

MODEL: See where I have routed the uploaded image files.

```
class Car(models.Model):

    def fileLocation(instance, filename):
        return 'media/cars/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.agent.username, os.path.basename(filename))

    make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    car_registration = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True) 
    insurance_exp = models.DateField(max_length=100)
    cost_per_day = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000) 
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
    image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
    image5 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
    available = models.BooleanField()
    added_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now()) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model
```

VIEW:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Car, Agent

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    all_cars = Car.objects.all()
    context = {'all_cars':all_cars}
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

TEMPLATE (home.html):

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">

    {% for car in all_cars %}
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 list-cars">
        <div class="media">


          <div class="media-left media-top">

        <a href="#">
             <img src="{{car.image1.url}}">

           </a>
          </div>

          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{{car.make}} {{car.model}}</h4>
            <p>{{car.description}} </p>
            <p class="price">Kshs {{car.cost_per_day}} Per Day</p>

            {% if car.available == True %}
                <button class="btn btn-success">Available</button>
            {% else %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Not Available</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">When will it be available?</button>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}



    </div>
</div>  




{% endblock %}
```

SETTINGS.PY:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
)
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from cars import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('cars.urls')),
]
```

RESULT:
[The images are not rendering properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWTgT.png)

Is something wrong with my path to the images?

Comment: Show your `urls.py` file. What serves static on your project?

Comment: You're missing the static serve configuration in the urls.py , please add it to your post so we can help you

Comment: HI, I have added the URLS.PY file in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer: I simply added the 'MEDIA' folder into the static folder and changed the URL of the images to start from 'STATIC'. The images display perfectly on the site.

```
class Car(models.Model):

def fileLocation(instance, filename):
    return 'static/media/cars/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.agent.username, os.path.basename(filename))

make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
year = models.IntegerField()
car_registration = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True) 
insurance_exp = models.DateField(max_length=100)
cost_per_day = models.IntegerField()
description = models.TextField(max_length=1000) 
agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
image5 = models.ImageField(upload_to=fileLocation)
available = models.BooleanField()
added_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now())
```

Right on the function fileLocation() I added the return 'static/....'. Then proceeded to embed the media folder into the static folder. And it worked.